# Why my simple single formula android calculator app apk of size 1.5 MB while some other good app apks are of small size in KBs

Tags: android, size

My simple single formula based android calculator app apk is of size 1.5 MB while some other good app apks are of small size in KBs, for example tankcalc.apk is about 50KB and doing lot more action than my app. And I have created same calculator app in C# in visual studio, it took just 46KB. I could not understand why android development taking so much size ???

my main_activity.java is 3KB and layout files are 1KB and 9KB. size of All images in mipmap is around 100KB.

Is there any way reduce the size of an android app??

the following is my build.gradle code

```
    apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.1"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.nextosho.dipcalculator"
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 23
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.0.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:23.0.1'
}
```

Comment: Probably it comes from libraries that you decided to use, like `appcompat-v7`. In general, it is impossible to answer your specific question, as we cannot see your app.

Comment: yes, is there a way to share my files here, so that i will upload them.

Comment: "is there a way to share my files here" -- not directly. You might consider editing your question and posting your `app/build.gradle` file (assuming that you have a conventional Android Studio project).

Comment: @commonware I have added build.gradle code

Comment: Extremely sorry, I was in hurry. I have changed it again

Answer (score 1):

You are using the `appcompat-v7` library. This adds ~1MB to an Android app.

Also, you are using the `design` library. That probably adds some size, but I do not know how much.

Your choices are:

1. Don't worry about the size.
2. Remove both libraries (as `design` requires `appcompat-v7`) and everything in your code that relies on those libraries (`AppCompatActivity`, `Theme.AppCompat`, etc.).

Comment: Thank you. Please I have another problem in my app. the code which is working well in my different apps, i put that code in a new app (swipe view with 3 tabs) each app code in each tab. The app installing,opening & displaying the way i wanted in three tabs. I have two buttons in each tab. CLEAR & CALCULATE. when i click those buttons (which are connected with ONCLICK to java code for calucation) the app is crashing. The same code is working well in all three different apps & Android studio also showing no errors in my java code. is there a way you can help me in this?

Comment: @SivaPrasad: Ask a separate Stack Overflow question. Provide a [mcve], which would include the complete Java stack trace associated with your crash, along with your code that is causing the crash. With luck, somebody will be able to help you.

Comment: Thank you very much